# Extracting words from a file in C

Tags: c++, c, linux

Could anyone help me to correct the following code. I
    need to extract words (sequence of non white space characters up to a white space character or a new line character). Here the code prints each letter of extracted word 3 times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
  FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;
  char ch,str[10],lab[10],opc[10],opd[10];
  int i;
  fp1=fopen("ma.dat","r");

  while((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
  {
 i=0;
    if(ch!=' ' || '\n' || -1)
    {
    lab[i++]=ch;
    }
    lab[i]='\0';
i=0;
    if(ch!=' ' || '\n' || -1)
    {
    opc[i++]=ch;
    }
    opc[i]='\0';
i=0;
    if(ch!=' ' || '\n' || -1)
    {
    opd[i++]=ch;
    }
    opd[i]='\0';


    printf("%s %s %s ",lab,opc,opd);

  }
  fcloseall();
}
```

and here is my input :

```
copy start 1000
 lda alpha
 lda five
 sta six
six word 4
alpha rword 5
five byte c'eof'
 end
```

and the output is :

```
c c c o o o p p p y y y       s s s t t t a a a r r r t t t       1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 


       l l l d d d a a a       a a a l l l p p p h h h a a a 


       l l l d d d a a a       f f f i i i v v v e e e 


       s s s t t t a a a       s s s i i i x x x 


 s s s i i i x x x       w w w o o o r r r d d d       4 4 4 


 a a a l l l p p p h h h a a a       r r r w w w o o o r r r d d d       5 5 5 


 f f f i i i v v v e e e       b b b y y y t t t e e e       c c c ' ' ' e e e o o o f f f ' ' ' 


       e e e n n n d d d
```

Here I used the logic that scan until eof reached and (tried) to get get separate words until some space or newline is reached.

Comment: What is a "word" to you? A sequence of non-whitespace characters terminated by a whitespace character or EOF? If so, it seems like it would be obvious how to read them, at least for someone who's going to write their own two-pass assembler.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   You will get good answers to good questions, but this one doesn't meet the guidelines.  Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and then consider how to demonstrate your at least minimal understanding of the problem being solved.   Showing how you've tried scanf would probably be a good start...

Comment: word meant to be a sequence of non-whitespace characters terminated by a whitespace character . it is to be read from a file with atmost 3 words in a line

Comment: You should read a book about teaching C to get the basics first. Good luck writing your assembler.

Comment: Can you suggest any good books?

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux). Perhaps read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) after a good C programming book (like a *recent edition* of [Kernighan & Ritchie : the C programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) ...)

Comment: You shouldn't assume EOF is -1 (though it almost always is).  You should review `if(ch!=' ' || '\n' || -1)` because (1) as written, it will always evaluate to true because `'\n'` is not zero, and (2) if you'd written `if (ch != ' ' || ch != '\n' || ch != EOF)` then it would still always be true because if `ch` is not a space, the first term is true, and if `ch` is a space the second term is true.  You probably had in mind `if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a debugger? Set a breakpoint and step through the program, line by line. You'll find that there is at least one statement in your loop that makes no sense. Hint: Why do you have the i=0 statement there inside the loop?

If this isn't just a typo after too many days of coding, you may want to read up on how

1. A while loop works. Especially which commands get repeated.
2. If works. Especially the difference between conditional statements like "if" and loop statements like "while".

PS - I'm obviously biased, but if you're looking for a good C tutorial, try my C tutorial http://masters-of-the-void.com - It's written for the Mac, but you already have your compiler up and running and you've compiled your own programs with it, so just doing the samples on Linux should be well within your skills.